# similarity between vectors of vectors

Tags: machine-learning, recommendation-engine

We are in the context of recommendations, where we want to recommend users to other users. Each user is represented as a vector with various attributes u=[a1, a2, a3].

Some of these attrs may be vectors themselves. Eg, a1 may be a vector of skills (where the user has only a subset of all possible skills). 
How do we compute similarity/distance between two users in this case? I guess we could flatten out all these sub-vectors, but is this a good solution?

Comment: Your suggestion makes sense; if it is a 'good' solution depends on the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Unfolding the individual values of the 'composite' vectors to 'usual' vectors seems a natural approach; afterwards, the [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) could be used.